# MATCH function displays an error on some cells but works for other

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Two sections of my table cannot process data because MATCH formula is displaying "Value not available" (values are present in range), for other five sections MATCH formula works.

I've tried changing ranges, cleaning/trimming range (to remove hidden chars), for some weird reason second section works when I changed lookup range from `$A$2:$A$1200 to $A$2:$A$1300` but left INDEX range at `$A$2:$A$1200`.

```
=CELL("address",INDEX($A$2:$A$1200,MATCH($AP8,$A$2:$A$1200)))
```

Expected result would be cell reference of first matching value in ascending order from lookup range, but first two sections are displaying #N/A error.

EDIT #1:

Data example:

```
    A         B        C        D
1 Name1     Name1

2 Name1     Name2

3 Name1

4 Name2

5 Name2

6 Name1

7 Name2

...(list is never completed as new data is always entered)
```

I want cell reference of specific Name that has been entered latest.
In this case it would be

```
 =CELL("address",INDEX(A1:A7,MATCH(B1,A1:A7)))
```

and expected result would be `$A$6`.

Comment: Provide your data please

Comment: `MATCH($AP8,$A$2:$A$1200)` is doing a Nearest Match ([see doc's here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/match-function-e8dffd45-c762-47d6-bf89-533f4a37673a?NS=EXCEL&Version=90&SysLcid=1033&UiLcid=1033&AppVer=ZXL900&HelpId=xlmain11.chm60112&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)).  You probably want `MATCH($AP8,$A$2:$A$1200,0)`

Comment: Using 0 in MATCH function gives me back first result from the top, without 0 function displays first result from bottom of data (which i need). I would be willing to provide the file if someone wants to help.

Comment: You are using the Match inside a Cell( Index()) construct. Please explain what you want to achieve. Maybe there is a better way. Post a few rows of sample data (no more than a dozen, keep it simple) and the expected results. Please read this carefully: Edit your post to provide this additional information. Do **not** put additional details into comments. Then post a comment to alert the people who are following this question.

Comment: I've added an example, and again I would be willing to share the file if its still unclear.

Comment: @Imran you say _Using 0 in MATCH function gives me back first result from the top, without 0 function displays first result from bottom of data_  Using 1 (the default) in Match **requires** the data to be sorted.  If you use 1 on unsorted data, what result you get will be pure luck.

Comment: @Imran you now have contradicting requirements in your Q: _Expected result would be cell reference of first matching value in ascending order from lookup range_ and _I want cell reference of specific Name that has been entered latest_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get *cell reference of specific Name that has been entered latest* you can't use `MATCH`.  But you can use `LOOKUP`, like this

```
=ADDRESS(LOOKUP(2,1/(A:A=C1),ROW(A:A)),1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **ADDRESS** function to return the expected cell address by finding the **row** and **column** number using either **LARGE** or **AGGREGATE** function as shown below:

`{=ADDRESS(LARGE(IFERROR(ROW(Col_A)/(Col_A=B2),0),1),COLUMN(Col_A),1)}`

or

`=ADDRESS(AGGREGATE(14,7,ROW(Col_A)/(Col_A=B3),1),COLUMN(Col_A),1)`

The first one is an **Array Formula** which means you need to press **Ctrl+Shift+Enter** to confirm.

See below screen-shot for clarifications. I have **named** the data in Column A as **Col_A**.

[image: Solution]

Cheers :)